# For a removed node in cluster version of Apache IoTDB, how to add it back and be able to check it?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How can I add the removed nodes back to the cluster OF Apache IoTDB? When setting this same node, does it have to be treated as a new node to be able to execute? I set it as a new node, restarted my IoTDB cluster and still cannot check it through configuration statements. Anyone know where did I do wrong or what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you already delete the original node, then you cannot add the node with the same name back to Apache IoTDB. You can only treat this node as a new node, rename it and add it back. If you now cannot see it in your cluster, then check if you delete the data directory of the original node. If not, delete it, and then restart the IoTDB system, and your problem should be solved.